# How can I make a change programmatically and add only that change (i.e. as if `-p` was given)?

Tags: git

I set up this pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
f="targetFile.js"
v="`awk -F'[ \t;]' '/^const __REV__ = /{print $4}' "$f"`"
v=$(($v + 1))
echo New rev: $v
sed -i '' -e 's:^const __REV__ = [0-9]\{1,\};$:const __REV__ = '$v';:' "$f"
```

to bump a revision number on each commit, e.g. change the line `const __REV__ = 99;` to `const __REV__ = 100;`.

In order to include the change in the current commit, I should do a `git add $f` as the last step.

However that would add the *whole file*, so it would not play nice with `git add -p` which I happen to use a lot to split large commits in logical chunks.

How it is possible to programmatically make a change and stage it without `add`ing the whole file to the staging area?

Constraints:

- there are already some staged changes, which we do not want to discard;

A few assumptions that can be made:

- the context around the line containing `const __REV__ =` will never be touched by user, so a conflict on that line is unlikely;
- that is the only line to contain `const __REV__ =`
- more...

I feel I should touch *both* the file in the working copy and the file in the staging area, and don't ever do `git add ...`, but I'd need some advice in doing this, as it looks something unorthodox.

Comment: No.  No. Don't.  NOO.  Don't do this.  Do *not* store a version inside the file.  Wherever you are using that value, instead derive it from the repo.  Programmatically modifying data in the repo is a bad practice.  Storing version info in the repo (rather than deriving it from the repo) is bad practice.  Don't compound the two.

Comment: If you need to deploy marked-up source outside of a repo, use `git archive` and the export-subst and export-ignore attributes. That works great, see the examples [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) for a starter kit. But inside your repo, see above: Don't. Do. It. It will hurt you in subtle and lasting ways. Imagine eating cajun gumbo except instead of a slow-rolling tide of heat, you get actual damage.

Comment: @WilliamPursell perhaps a middle ground might be that if you are storing versions in a file, separate out the version portion such that only an automated process updates the version file. (And this would probably also solve the current staging hunks issue too.)